# how can I call this function in cython?

Tags: c++, python, numpy, cython

what is the best way to call this function in cython with only numpy?
I am not going to use ctypes, memcpy, malloc etc..

function 1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" void cfun(const void * indatav, int rowcount, int colcount,
void * outdatav);

void cfun(const void * indatav, int rowcount, int colcount, void *
outdatav) {
    //void cfun(const double * indata, int rowcount, int colcount,
double * outdata) {
    const double * indata = (double *) indatav;
    double * outdata = (double *) outdatav;
    int i;
    puts("Here we go!");
    for (i = 0; i < rowcount * colcount; ++i) {
        outdata[i] = indata[i] * 4;
    }
    puts("Done!");
}
```

function 2)

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void cfun(const double ** indata, int
rowcount, int colcount, double ** outdata) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colcount; ++j) {
            outdata[i][j] = indata[i][j] * 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Wonjun, Choi

Comment: There's no need to call those functions from python. You can just do the same things using numpy

Comment: the reason I have to do this is I need to wrap some existing c,c++ library.. so.. just making the numpy function will not be a solution. that's why I posted simple example like above.

Comment: post the real functions then, post your attempt of code and the errors you're getting

Answer (score 2):

You can 'call' the function directly from Cython by declaring it as *extern*.

```
cdef extern from "mylibraryheader.h":
    void cfun1(void* indatav, int rowcount, int colcount, void* outdatav)
    void cfun2(double** indata, int rowcount, int colcount, doubke** outdata)
```

You can now call these functions like in C/C++. Note that there is no *const* keyword in Cython, you can leave it out. Unfortunately I can not give you an example of how to convert the NumPy array into an array of *double*. But here is an example of running it from a list of doubles.

```
cdef extern from "mylibraryheader.h":
    void cfun1(void* indatav, int rowcount, int colcount, void* outdatav)
    void cfun2(double** indata, int rowcount, int colcount, double** outdata)

cdef extern from "stdlib.h":
    ctypedef int size_t
    void* malloc(size_t)
    void free(void*)

def py_cfunc1(*values):
    cdef int i = 0
    cdef int size = sizeof(double)*len(values)
    cdef double* indatav = <double*> malloc(size)
    cdef double* outdatav = <double*> malloc(size)
    cdef list outvalues = []
    for v in values:
        indatav[i] = <double>v
        i += 1
    cfun1(<void*>indatav, 1, len(values), <void*>outdatav)
    for 0 <= i < len(values):
        outvalues.append(outdatav[i])
    return outvalues
```

*Note: Untested*

Answer (score 0):

You can't *call* this function from cython - you have to *write* it as a cython function - some good examples are [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html). As a reference, function 1):

```
cimport numpy as np

def cfun(np.ndarray indata, int rowcount, int colcount, np.ndarray outdata):
    cdef int i
    print("Here we go!")
    for i in range(rowcount * colcount):
        outdata[i] = indata[i] * 4
    print("Done!")
```

If you really want to call this you will have to use ctypes or write your own wrapper. Using [swig](http://www.swig.org/) would also work.

Comment: would you make me an example for function 2) ?